# ¿Por qué cambia la hora en el servidor, en un campo de un objeto, si esta se estableció en el cliente?

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
const data = {
        id: uuidv4(),
        subcatId: '5ff8a4f7d3a8edd01ef1fa45',
        post:
            {
              title: this.title,
              text: this.contents,
              tags: this.select,
              createdAt: new Date(),
              publishedAt: this.myDate,
              comments: this.comments
            }
      }
```

Al hacer un console.log de este objeto, se visualiza:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como podéis ver, en el campo createdAt se estableció su valor a la fecha/hora actuales. Esto ocurre en el cliente.

Al instante, en el servidor se ve lo siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi pregunta es: ¿cómo hago para preservar la hora enviada desde el cliente (Javascript) a un programa ubicado en mi propio equipo escrito en NodeJS?

Gracias.

Comment: Si te fijas, **no la está cambiando**, solo está cambiando **como te la muestra**. En el cliente, es `GMT+0100`, mientras que en el servidor es `GMT` solo. Ambas horas son la misma, pero con diferente representación.

Comment: Gracias, @Juanjo. 
¿Cómo puedo hacer para cambiar la representación? 
Tanto el servidor como el cliente es el mismo ordenador.

Comment: JS no es lo mio ... pero creo que este es un buen sitio para comenzar: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como dice [Juanjo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/149531/juanjo) es la misma hora pero el servidor guarda el formato `GMT`, esta pregunta sale de vez en cuándo de manera periódica entonces voy a tomarme el tiempo de responderla de una manera más amplia para que sea fácil de encontrar para nuevos usuarios.

### ¿Qué contiene en realidad mi objeto `Date`?

Ahora, para que entiendas mejor como funcionan las fechas en JS creo que lo mejor es miremos cómo es que realmente funciona el objeto `Date`, leyendo de la documentación:

> JavaScript Date objects represent a single moment in time in a
> platform-independent format. Date objects contain a Number that
> represents milliseconds since 1 January 1970 UTC.

Traducción:

> Los objetos `Date` de JavaScript representan un único momento en el
> tiempo en un formato que no depende de la plataforma. Los objetos
> `Date` contienen una variable tipo `Number` que representa el tiempo
> en milisegundos desde 01/01/1970 UTC.

Cuando usas `Date` no estás guardando alguna string como las que ves cuando imprimes en consola, lo que realmente guardas es una cantidad de tiempo después de un evento de referencia ([Epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(computing))).

### ¿Porqué es así?

Porque todos tienen zonas horarias distintas, si yo me hice mi café a las 11AM hoy (hace 20 minutos) para una persona en Alemania también ocurrió hace 20 minutos, pero a las 5PM. Por lo tanto los servidores deben de guardar los eventos de tiempo con una referencia que pueda ser entendida por cualquier persona sin importar en dónde en el mundo esté.

### Entonces ¿Cómo hago para que mis usuarios puedan obtener la hora real de los eventos, desde su punto de vista (zona horaria)?

1. Guardas el tiempo en tu base de datos con un formato refrenciado, por
   ejemplo `GMT`, `UTC`, o inclusive el `Epoch Time` (que es difil de
   interpretar para un humano normal, se vería como así: `1610214211`).
2. Obtienes el el tiempo de tu base de datos desde el explorador del cliente.
3. Cuando lo vas a mostrar al usuario lo conviertes por medio de la configuración  de zona horaria que tiene en su dispositivo.

### ¿Cómo hago esto en JS?

Por medio de [`toLocaleString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Date/toLocaleString), por ejemplo:

```js
//Simulamos que esta función obtiene los datos del servidor
function obtenerDatoDelServidor() {

  const pago = {
    usuario: "franacuna",
    id: "666",
    cantidad: "3",
    moneda: "USD",
    fecha: "Sat Jan 09 2021 17:48:50 GMT"
  }
  return pago;

}

//Esta función le indica al usuario el ultimo pago que realizo

function obtenerUltimoPago() {
  const {
    usuario,
    cantidad,
    moneda,
    fecha
  } = obtenerDatoDelServidor();

  //Convertimos la string a objeto por medio del constructor de Date
  let fechaLocal = new Date(fecha);

  //Convertimos el objeto a la fecha local, 
  //JS toma en cuenta la configuracion de zona horaria de mi dispositivo
  fechaLocal = fechaLocal.toLocaleString();

  //O podrías hacer const fechaLocal = new Date(fecha).toLocaleString()

  console.log(`El usuario ${usuario} realizo un pago de ${cantidad}${moneda}, la fecha:${fechaLocal}`);
}

obtenerUltimoPago();
```

### Un ejemplo de que pasaría si no tuvieran en cuenta las zonas horarias

Imagina que implementaste un sistema de teleconferencias, en los cuáles puedes agendar una reunión e invitar a diferentes usuarios para conversar por medio de una videollamada (estilo Zoom, Skype, GoogleMeetings, etc).

Supongamos que yo soy un usuario de tu plataforma (vivo en Costa Rica) y decido agendar una videollamada con dos personas de Brasil. Para esto ingreso a tu plataforma lleno el formulario para agendar la reunion para mañana a las 6pm y presiono el botón "Agendar" que se encarga de enviar el request al servidor y consecuentemente la invitación a los brasileños.

Justo en ese momento se genera en tu base de datos una entrada con los datos:

```
reunion:{
    id: 45781,
    usuario: "franacuna@correo.com",
    invitados: ["brasileno1@correo.com","brasileno2@correo.com"],
    fecha: "10 Enero 2020, 16:00:00"
}
```

Al día siguiente a las 3:30pm recibo un correo del los brasileños preguntando que porqué no hay nadie en la reunión. Yo extrañado reviso en tu plataforma la hora a la que había programado la teleconferencia y confirmo que es a las 6 de la tarde y que faltan todavía 2 horas y media para que empiece.

El fallo está en que mi plataforma solo guarda la hora de manera local, por lo tanto las fechas que guardaste solo serán relevantes para las personas que compartan mi zona horaria. Si hubiese guardado la fecha con una referencia como GMT los dispositivos que consultan la hora podrían convertir la hora por medio de la zona horaria configurada en sus dispositivos.

Comment: Al final opté por este método (el guardar el timestamp en ese formato que indicas).
Muchísimas gracias.