# Error al mostrar fechas desde la base de datos en reactjs

Tags: javascript, base-de-datos, reactjs, datepicker, react-bootstrap

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación en React.Js.

Cuando selecciono y guardo las fechas usando `react-date-picker`, las guardo bien en la base de datos. Pero cuando los muestro con `react-bootstrap-table-next` y `react-bootstrap/Table`, no se muestran correctamente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para `react-date-picker`:

```
...
<DatePicker onChange={d => setDt(d)} value={date} />
```

Para `react-bootstrap-table-next`:

```
<BootstrapTable
  bootstrap4
  keyField="id"
  data={data}
  columns={columns}
  pagination={paginationFactory(options)}
 />
```

Para `react-bootstrap/Table`:

```
{
  array.map(item => {
    return <tr>
             <td>{item.id}</td>
             <td>{item.date}</td>
             <td>{item.hour}</td>
           </tr>

  })
}
```

Parece haber un problema en cómo lee el valor de la fecha.

Quizás lo que se necesita hacer es verificar la información de la configuración regional entre la base de datos y el cliente, y hacer una conversión para cambiar la configuración.

¿Cómo puedo solucionar esto, sugerencias?

Comment: ¿Esta [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/419592/por-qu%c3%a9-cambia-la-hora-en-el-servidor-en-un-campo-de-un-objeto-si-esta-se-est/419649#419649) te ayuda?

Comment: Hola! Gracias por tu ayuda. Sí, es útil, aunque sigue sin mostrarme el valor correcto. creo que la solución está en darle formato a la celda.

Comment: Si compartes como es que obtienes tus datos desde la base de datos (tal vez con un console.log) podría ayudarte.

Comment: Muchas gracias! Lo solucioné usando la librería.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución que encontré temporalmente (quizás sea la forma de hacerlo), fue usar [moment](https://momentjs.com), como se sugiere en https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51278910/how-to-use-the-moment-library-in-react-bootstrap-tables-column-definition.

Hay que darle formato a la celda:

```
moment(cell).format("YYYY-MM-DD")
```